# RTC version control code checkout into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rtc

I am new to RTC and i have to checkout code from RTC to eclipse.
I have installed p2 repository plugin in eclipse. I have no idea how to checkout code in eclipse. I googled the net but was not able to find a solution. Following are my queries:

1. How to checkout the code into eclipse in normal J2EE format.
2. How to load the binaries into web-inf/lib folder automatically.

Any link for tutorial or any knowledge share would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> How to checkout the code into eclipse in normal J2EE format

This has nothing to do with J2EE: you load an RTC component in a sandbox (or local RTC workspace).

You can do that from the official RTC client, or from an Eclipse with RTC installed.
Note that there is a [difference between the eclipse workspace and the sandbox for RTC?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/124251/is-there-a-difference-between-the-eclipse-workspace-and-the-sandbox-for-rtc)

> How to load the binaries into web-inf/lib folder automatically.

This isn't done by RTC. RTC will load your files in a sandbox.
Then you can run your own script which would update any other directory structure that you want.

Comment: Thank you, is there a sample script which does that, i.e picking the jar from rtc and storing in your local file system.

Comment: @user1834664 not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

**How to load the binaries into web-inf/lib folder automatically.**

If your project is mavenized then you need to just update the maven dependencies, it will pull all mentioned jars to u r dependency folder.